How to use Angular 18 with JWplayer
I am trying to create a streams (live video) on my Angular 18 app with using JWplayer. But it isn't working at all and I don't get why.

I tryed to install JWplayer like a npm library, but is was error
[error img](https://i.sstatic.net/E4JhiD3Z.png) 
(I don't know some more ways to install libraries to Angular or how to fix my errors.)
And I Can't connect JWplayer to my app component

So I want to ask help with connecting JWplayer to my Angular 18 component. Like. How I can do it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please do not upload images oferrors. Also, during the packages install, there is no error, it's just warnings about potential vulnerabilities. The install itself was successful. Please edit the question and add the code you have added to integrate the package. Also clarify what is not working, including additional information, such as error messages.
